# Activity Gauze Highchart DataLabel

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a [Activity Gauze Highchart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity). Everything is working fine except I am facing difficulties in managing the DataLabels.

As you can see if you run the below code, the data labels are rendering fine and even rotating with the series path. But they are just messed up for the series which have really small values.

Is there anyway by which I can either hide it for the smaller series or I can keep it outside from the arc (see here for reference https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Activity',
    style: {
      fontSize: '24px'
    }
  },


  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360,
    background: [{ // Track for Move
      outerRadius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }, { // Track for Exercise
      outerRadius: '87%',
      innerRadius: '63%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }, { // Track for Stand
      outerRadius: '62%',
      innerRadius: '38%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }]
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickPositions: []
  },

  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function(){
          return "Really really long data label";
        },
        enabled: true,
        allowOverlap: true,
        zIndex: 10,
        crop: false,
        overflow: "allow",
        textPath: {
          enabled: true,
          attributes: {
            textAnchor: 'start',
            startOffset: 5,
            dy: 15
          }
        }
      },
      linecap: 'round',
      stickyTracking: false,
      rounded: true
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Move',
    data: [{
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      radius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      y: 80
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Exercise',
    data: [{
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
      radius: '87%',
      innerRadius: '63%',
      y: 65
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Stand',
    data: [{
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
      radius: '62%',
      innerRadius: '38%',
      y: 10
    }]
  }]
});
```

```css
#container{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out the `getDataLabelPath` function is not implemented yet for the `solidgauge` series. I reported it as a feature enhancement on the Highcharts GitHub issue channel where you can share your opinion.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14158

And here is my basic attempt of implementing this feature:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nfwvos5j/

```
(function(H) {
  H.seriesTypes.solidgauge.prototype.pointClass.prototype.getDataLabelPath = function(label) {
    var renderer = this.series.chart.renderer,
      shapeArgs = this.shapeArgs,
      upperHalf = this.angle < 0 || this.angle > Math.PI,
      start = shapeArgs.start,
      end = shapeArgs.end,
      radians = end - start;
    if (!this.dataLabelPath) {
      this.dataLabelPath = renderer
        .arc({
          open: true
        })
        // Add it inside the data label group so it gets destroyed
        // with the label
        .add(label);
    }

    this.dataLabelPath.attr({
      x: shapeArgs.x,
      y: shapeArgs.y,
      r: (shapeArgs.r +
        (this.dataLabel.options.distance || 0)),
      start: start,
      end: end,
      clockwise: 1,
    });

    this.outerArcLength = radians * this.dataLabelPath.r

    return this.dataLabelPath;
  }
})(Highcharts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dataLabels formatter callback](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.DataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction). In the calback, this keyword refers to [the data label context of type PointLabelObject](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.PointLabelObject).

Something like this:

```
dataLabels: {
    formatter: function(options){
        if(this.series.name === 'Stand') {
            return null;
        } else {
            return this.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the labels are dynamic. I do not know which label is not going to fit in the series.